# Nested Dictionary in R

Tags: r, dictionary

I'm more used to a python environment. Is there a way to produce a dictionary/list that is fully dynamic. I.e. that I could create flexible data structures say that relate to a particular number such as

```
[1:["var_a":6, "var_b":3],2:[..]]
```

Where I will not know how may elements in each list. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `list(list(var_a=6,var_b=3), ...)`

Comment: @JuliánUrbano but can I access like a dictionary? because I may have [4:["var_a":6, "var_b":3],7:[..]]

Comment: yes, you can. See my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
> a <- list()
> a[[1]] <- list(var_a=6)
> a[[1]]$var_b = 3
> a[[2]] <- list(var_c=8)

> a[[1]]
$var_a
[1] 6

$var_b
[1] 3    
> a[[1]]["var_b"]
$var_b
[1] 3
> a[[2]]$var_c
[1] 8
```

Answer (score 3):

As @JulianUrbano says, a `list` is a flexible data structure in R.

It's a vector:

```
l <- list()
is.vector(l)
```

That can take names:

```
l2 <- list( a = 1 , l = l )
l2[["a"]]
l2[1:2]
```